# Jquery ajax displays [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I basically have 2 drop-down lists and 2 labels.

The first drop-down list is the category selection and the second list loads dynamically the items based on the category.

All is good until now.

At the labels I am trying to display the ItemName and the ItemDescription.

ItemName displays fine but when it comes to ItemDescription for some reason it shows [object Object].

I noticed in console that ItemDescription information is posted correctly, can you please help me find the way to display it correctly?

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#ItemsDivId').hide();
        $('#SubmitID').hide();
        $('#ItemTypeID').on('change', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetItemTypeForm")',
                data: { itemTypeId: $('#ItemTypeID').val() },
            success: function (results) {
                var options = $('#ItemsID');
                options.empty();
                options.append($('<option />').val(null).text("- Select an Item -"));
                $.each(results, function () {
                    options.append($('<option />').val(this.ItemsID).text(this.Value));                 

                });             

                $('#ItemsDivId').show();                                         

                $('#ItemsID').change(function (results) {

                    $('#SubmitID').show();

                    $('#ItemName').text($("#ItemsID option:selected").text());
                    $('#ItemDescription').text($("#ItemsID option:selected").text(this.ItemDescription));
                });

            }
            });


    });
</script>
```

Json:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetItemTypeForm(string itemTypeId)
        {
            //pseudo code
            var data = from s in db.Items
                       where s.ItemType.ItemTypeName == itemTypeId && s.ItemActive == true
                       select new { Value = s.ItemName, ItemsID = s.ItemId ,ItemDescription = s.ItemDescription };


            return Json(data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#ItemsID option:selected").text(this.ItemDescription);` changes the text and returns the element as an object. You can save the description of each item as data with jquery `data()` function. Then use it in `change` event..

try changing to this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#ItemsDivId').hide();
        $('#SubmitID').hide();
        $('#ItemTypeID').on('change', function () {
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetItemTypeForm")',
                data: { itemTypeId: $('#ItemTypeID').val() },
            success: function (results) {
                var options = $('#ItemsID');
                options.empty();
                options.append($('<option />').val(null).text("- Select an Item -"));
                options.data('description','');
                $.each(results, function () {
                    options.append($('<option />').val(this.ItemsID).text(this.Value));                 
                    options.data('description',this.ItemDescription);
                });             

                $('#ItemsDivId').show();                                         

                $('#ItemsID').change(function (results) {
                    $('#SubmitID').show();
                    $('#ItemName').text($("#ItemsID option:selected").text());
                    $('#ItemDescription').text($("#ItemsID option:selected").data('description'));
                });

            }
         });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: nop it doesnt work , the ItemDescription label gives me the Item Name instead of the Item Description

Comment: Yes, the post in console has 3 elements with their information: Value, ItemId and ItemDescription

Comment: Sorry for the delay , just checked your code but it gets nothing displayed at the label of ItemDescription

Answer (score 0):

I did some play around and I found the solution :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#ItemsDivId').hide();
        $('#SubmitID').hide();
        $('#ItemTypeID').on('change', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetItemTypeForm")',
                data: { itemTypeId: $('#ItemTypeID').val() },
                success: function (results) {
                    var options = $('#ItemsID');
                    options.empty();
                    options.append($('<option />').val(null).text("- Select an Item -"));
                    options.data('description', '');
                    $.each(results, function () {
                        options.append($('<option />').val(this.ItemsID).text(this.Value).data('ItemDescription', this.ItemDescription));                   
                    });

                    $('#ItemsDivId').show();

                    $('#ItemsID').change(function (results) {
                        $('#SubmitID').show();
                        $('#ItemName').text($("#ItemsID option:selected").text());
                        $('#ItemDescription').text($("#ItemsID option:selected").data('ItemDescription'));
                    });

                }
        });
        });
</script>
```

Also many thanks to Sampath Liyanage for leading me to the right direction :)